# css panel with image and text

Tags: html, css, hover, panel

I have a css border panel, rendered with this code:

```
#bor_panel {
border-radius: 12px;
border: 2px solid #297293;
padding: 20px; 
width: 170px;
height: 170px;    
}
```

and used in a page in this way:

```
<div id="bor_panel"></div>
```

I need to put in the panel an image and a text In this way. If I hover the image with the mouse, the image disappears and the text appears. How can I do? I tried different techninques but they lose the position inside the panel.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#bor_panel {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #297293;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#bor_panel:hover img {
  display: none;
}

#bor_panel:hover span {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="bor_panel">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/170x140">
  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! If I would a text under the original image? And this text disappears with the hover

Answer (score 0):

css

```
#bor_panel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #297293;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;    
}

#bor_panel:hover .image{
  display: none;
}

#bor_panel:hover h4{
  display: block;
}

h4{
  display: none;
}
```

html

```
<div id="bor_panel">
    <div class="image">insert image</div>
    <h4>text</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

2. No change html.

```css
#bor_panel {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #297293;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/170');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

#bor_panel:hover {
  background-image: none;
}

#bor_panel:hover::after {
  content: 'Lorem ipsum';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="bor_panel"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! If I would a text under the original image? And this text disappears with the hover

Comment: sorry english is not my native language. did not understand what is hanging?

Comment: If the content that has to disappear was image+text under the image?

Comment: Then you need to change html. I change my othet answer. See it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see this new part.

Comment: I saw your code but I need something like this:       
 https://imgur.com/a/jLh9w and when the mouse is over the image, another text appears